# Why isn't my Novaworks theme design updating on front end after I edit and save configuration?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, design, edit

First off, let me apologize and thank you for the pain you may endure with my amateur explanation.

I have a custom theme set up on Magento, that gives me the option of editing the theme design, i.e. color of font, background, button hover, menu drop down, etc.  I've successfully managed to change it a few times- although the change would only work in, lets say, Google Chrome on some computers but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer- vice versa.  This time around, I changed it from purple to blue but it doesn't work in *any* of the web browsers, yet for some reason it's working when I view it from my phone.. *sigh*.

[image]

Something even more painful is that when I view the front end from another computer (I'm in an office with 10 computers that I bounce around to) it still has the color theme (red) that I had set 2 changes ago.

I've flushed Magento cache & cache storage, refreshed all cache storage management, re-entered the color hex and saved the configuration, enabled the Load Custom CSS option in customization settings, I thought maybe enabling the WYSIWYG editor would help but that didn't do anything either..

I've googled everything and either I don't understand or my question hasn't been asked before or I'm just not searching properly- either way, somebody please help me. I'm turning into Cartman from the stress of searching and searching and searching...

[image]

Thank you !!

Comment: Appreciate the time & effort you put into posting this question, but ultimately it comes down to getting support from the extension/theme author or providing us enough resources to troubleshoot - perhaps a link to a public instance so that the CSS could be inspected. You can edit your post and add relevant info and we may reopen.